# 3rdparty repository issues with maven pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, migration, maven-2, pom.xml, birt

I was looking for BIRT Dependency in the net. Package my code refers are

```
import org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.Chart;
import org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute.Anchor;
```

It is using chartengineapi and below is the maven dependency entry for POM.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt/chartengineapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>chartengineapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Since it is part of other repository (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/) it gives error in Pom.xml. Could any one help me to sort out this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added repository tag and resolved.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Add one more `<repository></repository>` and the give the new repo name and link. It worked for me though I am not sure whether this is a standard approach.